# WPF DataGrid has RowEditEnding but no RowEditEnded

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've bound an ObservableCollection to a DataGrid. When I change values in the DataGrid, the RowEditEnding event is raised. But the e.Row.Item is the object before editing, so you don't see the new values. I understand that because of the EditEnding. In Silverlight you have an EditEnded event, how can I get the object with the new values when I edit the DataGrid.

thanks,

Filip

Answer (score 13):

From https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c38fc695-d1ec-4252-87b7-feb484ee01e4/wpf-4-datagrid-roweditending, change the UpdateSourceTrigger of the Binding to PropertyChanged. The Property will then be updated immediately, before the RowEditEnding event, and the new value can be accessed from the RowEditEnding event handler.

For example, for a DataGridComboBoxColumn

```
SelectedItemBinding="{Binding ForTestResult, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

This seems a very simple way to solve this issue.

In addition, although I have not tried it, I think it should be easy to also access the original value before editing if your object implements IEditableObject.

Comment: Won't work for formatted values dates, decimals etc. Only for strings.

Comment: I also think that this should be the answer, so i upvoted

Answer (score 6):

Well, maybe this may help: http://wpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=39356

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vinsibal/archive/2009/04/14/5-more-random-gotchas-with-the-wpf-datagrid.aspx

Or this, see point number 5.

You'll have to tinker with it to get what you want I think, but I hope that helps! Or points you in a good direction.

Comment: Can't believe MS has still not implemented such a basic event. For teh first time its easier in Silverlight than in WPF. :)  The second link point 5 is the answer!!! Worked for me.  Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solution seems simple enough. Referred from [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b78d4c19-740e-4b3c-a285-eb42ed39c15d/wpf-datagridroweditended?forum=wpf).

```
private void dgEmployees_RowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
{           
    Action action = delegate
                  {
                     Employee emp = e.Row.Item as Employee;
                    //do something nice to the employee                
                   };
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the ObservableCollection's changed event.

I bound to a DataTable and used the RowChanged event.

Comment: Doesn't work when changing one property of a item in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

My fresh and IMHO fastest way is to add `bool rowEdited=false`, then set it to `true` inside `DataGrid_RowEditEnding` and put your code for 'editEnded' inside `DataGrid_LayoutUpdated`:

```
if (rowEdited)
{
    //main code here//
    rowEdited=false;
}
```

.