# WPF Datagrid RowEditEnding in an MVVM environment

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, prism

I've been trying to capture the values that a user enters into a datagrid by using

```
<b:Interaction.Triggers>
    <b:EventTrigger EventName="RowEditEnding">
        <b:InvokeCommandAction  Command="{Binding ReleaseRowEditEndingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedRelease}"/>
    </b:EventTrigger>
```

But this doesn't work and I now understand this afte reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907701/wpf-datagrid-has-roweditending-but-no-roweditended) article on StackOverflow.  The solutions presented all seem to be based on directly calling a method signature that matches the event being raised, in this case

```
private void OnRowEditEnding(object sender, DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs e)
```

Has anyone accomplished getting the values post-rowedit in an MVVM situation?  All the solutions seem to tightly bind the event to the XAML and I'd like to avoid that, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was actually easier than I thought.  I changed the XAML and I can now get the values in the RowEditEnding event on the View Model.  Here's the before on the data columns on the datagrid:

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Paid" Binding="{Binding IsPaid, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

After

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Is Paid" Binding="{Binding IsPaid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Amount" Binding="{Binding Amount,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Just for the record  UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus does the trick too . It is useful when you use string formating and you dont want a mess

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping your data in a ListCollectionView and binding the DataGrid to the ListCollectionView. Then, in your ViewModel, hook into the ListCollectionView.CurrentChanging event to process your changes before moving to the new row.